# Valor padrão com imaskjs

Tags: javascript, input, mask

Eu criei uma máscara utilizando [imaskjs](https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs) para valor monetário num input HTML:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("txtTeste");

var maskOptions = {
    mask: Number,
    scale: 2,
    thousandsSeparator: ".",
    padFractionalZeros: true,
    normalizeZeros: true,
    radix: ",",
    mapToRadix: ["."],
    min: -999999999.99,
    max: 999999999.99
};

var mask = IMask(element, maskOptions);
```

Tem alguma propriedade de valor padrão para quando o usuário digitar um valor nulo?

Comment: Coloca uma verificação ao sair do campo...
Vamos se dizer que o usuário entrou no campo e não colocou nada, ao sair do campo (focusout()) você coloca o seu valor "padrão"

Comment: @Azzi essa é a forma que faço hoje, porém se essa biblioteca tivesse uma outra forma, ficaria mais fácil.

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui passando uma função para a chave "commit":

```js
var maskOptions = {
    mask: Number,
    scale: 2,
    thousandsSeparator: ".",
    padFractionalZeros: true,
    normalizeZeros: true,
    radix: ",",
    mapToRadix: ["."],
    min: -999999999.99,
    max: 999999999.99,
    commit: function (value, masked) {
        if (trim(value + "") == "") {
            masked._value = "0,00";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Perfeito, agora foi!